# Matlab implementation of Perceptron - can't seem to fix plotting

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

This is my first go with ML (and Matlab) and I'm following "Learning From Data" by Yaser S. Abu-Mostafa.

I'm trying to implement the Perceptron algorithm, after trying to go through the pseudocode, using other people's solutions I can't seem to fix my problem (I went through other threads too).

The algorithm separates the data fine, it works. However, I want to plot a single line, but it seems as it separates them in a way so the '-1' cluster is divided to a second cluster or more.

This is the code:

```
iterations = 100;
dim = 3;

X1=[rand(1,dim);rand(1,dim);ones(1,dim)];   % class '+1'
X2=[rand(1,dim);1+rand(1,dim);ones(1,dim)]; % class '-1'
X=[X1,X2];
Y=[-ones(1,dim),ones(1,dim)];
w=[0,0,0]';
% call perceptron
wtag=weight(X,Y,w,iterations);
% predict
ytag=wtag'*X;


% plot prediction over origianl data

figure;hold on

plot(X1(1,:),X1(2,:),'b.')
plot(X2(1,:),X2(2,:),'r.')
plot(X(1,ytag<0),X(2,ytag<0),'bo')
plot(X(1,ytag>0),X(2,ytag>0),'ro')
legend('class -1','class +1','pred -1','pred +1')


%Why don't I get just one line?
plot(X,Y);
```

The weight function (Perceptron):

```
function [w] = weight(X,Y,w_init,iterations)
%WEIGHT Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

w = w_init;
for iteration = 1 : iterations  %<- was 100!
  for ii = 1 : size(X,2)         %cycle through training set
    if sign(w'*X(:,ii)) ~= Y(ii) %wrong decision?
      w = w + X(:,ii) * Y(ii);   %then add (or subtract) this point to w
    end
  end
  sum(sign(w'*X)~=Y)/size(X,2);   %show misclassification rate
end
```

**I don't think the problem is in the second function but I added it regardless**

I'm pretty sure the algorithm separates it to more than one cluster but I can't tell why most of the learning I've done so far was math and theory and not actual coding so I'm probably missing something obvious..

Comment: Why do you think the output should be a line? Its not, it shoudl not be. Is that your question? that you are plotting a line but its not a line? Then all the ML stuff is unnecessary, isnt it? or is your question a different one? Its a bit unclear.

Comment: Hey Ander, I'm sorry if it's unclear; I've used the perceptron, and it separates the data according to how it should have. What I'm trying to do is have a 'physical' line (kind of like a border) that separates the red dots from the blue dots. I'm not sure what to change in the code where I plot X and Y.

Comment: A perceptron will indeed separate the inputs, but what it does is for input `[x1,x2]` it will give a numerical value to the output `y`, that is 0 or 1. In order to see that line that you want, you need to generate a `meshgrid` of x1,x2 and run all the values in the perceptron. That will give you a surface you can plot, from where you can get a contour. Thats a way of doing it at least